# Python Regular Expression Matching: ## ##

Tags: python, regex

I'm searching a file line by line for the occurrence of ##random_string##. It works except for the case of multiple #...

```
pattern='##(.*?)##'
prog=re.compile(pattern)

string='lala ###hey## there'
result=prog.search(string)

print re.sub(result.group(1), 'FOUND', string)
```

Desired Output:

```
"lala #FOUND there"
```

Instead I get the following because its grabbing the whole ###hey##:

```
"lala FOUND there"
```

So how would I ignore any number of # at the beginning or end, and only capture "##string##".

Comment: be careful with using lazy quantifiers like `(.*?)` because it'd match '##abc#####' and capture 'abc###'. also lazy quantifiers are very slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match at least two hashes at either end:

```
pattern='##+(.*?)##+'
```

Comment: im sorry i stated my question badly. i want to match EXACTLY
 ##<string>## and ignore the other ### at the beg or end (im calling re.sub and it will mess with my results).

Comment: @nubme: I'm not sure what you mean. That's exactly what my answer does. I just tested it, and confirmed that it outputs `hey` and will only match if the string has at least two `#` characters at each end.

Comment: @marcelo: sorry i edited my question, see if it makes more sense now.

Comment: @nubme: I'm sorry, but you've confused me even more, now. The code has an error in it, and when I replace `line` with `string` (is that the right fix?) to make it work, I don't get either of the outputs you indicate.

Comment: @marcelo: ya i mean string. thanks for your help i think i figured it out, but its kinda messy. #{2}([^#].?*)#{2}

Comment: `#{2}` == `##`, and `[^#].?*` isn't what you want, since it means "one non-hash character followed by zero or more non-line-end characters." The `*` only refers to the previous token, `.?`.  Generally, you shouldn't use `*`, `+`, or `?` consecutively; `*?` == `+?` == `?+` == `?*` == `*`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with your inner match.  You use `.`, which matches *any* character that isn't a line end, and that means it matches `#` as well.  So when it gets `###hey##`, it matches `(.*?)` to `#hey`.

The easy solution is to exclude the `#` character from the matchable set:

```
prog = re.compile(r'##([^#]*)##')
```

Protip: Use raw strings (e.g. `r''`) for regular expressions so you don't have to go crazy with backslash escapes.

Trying to allow `#` inside the hashes will make things **much** more complicated.

**EDIT:** If you do not want to allow blank inner text (i.e. "####" shouldn't match with an inner text of ""), then change it to:

```
prog = re.compile(r'##([^#]+)##')
```

`+` means "one or more."

Answer (score 1):

`'^#{2,}([^#]*)#{2,}'`    -- any number of # >= 2 on either end

be careful with using lazy quantifiers like (.*?) because it'd match '##abc#####' and capture 'abc###'. also lazy quantifiers are very slow

Comment: I think he wants at least 2 at beginning *and* end.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "block comment trick": `/##((?:[^#]|#[^#])+?)##/`
[image: Screenshot of working example]

Answer (score 0):

Adding + to regex, which means to match one or more character.

```
pattern='#+(.*?)#+'
prog=re.compile(pattern)

string='###HEY##'
result=prog.search(string)
print result.group(1)
```

Output:

```
HEY
```

Answer (score 0):

have you considered doing it non-regex way?

```
>>> string='lala ####hey## there'
>>> string.split("####")[1].split("#")[0]
'hey'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> text= 'lala ###hey## there'
>>> matcher= re.compile(r"##[^#]+##")
>>> print matcher.sub("FOUND", text)
lala #FOUND there
>>>
```