# Python Regular Expression Matching ## ##

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Regular Expression Matching: ## ##](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001980/python-regular-expression-matching)

I already asked this question, but let me restate it better... Im searching a file line by line for the occurrence of ##random_string##. It works except for the case of multiple #...

```
pattern='##(.*?)##'
prog=re.compile(pattern)

string='lala ###hey## there'
result=prog.search(string)

print re.sub(result.group(1), 'FOUND', line)
```

Desired Output:

```
"lala #FOUND there"
```

Instead I get the following because its grabbing the whole ###hey##:

```
"lala FOUND there"
```

So how would i ignore any number of # at the beg or end, and only capture "##string##".

Comment: Edit your existing question; don't post a new copy to clarify.  possible duplicate of [Python Regular Expression Matching: ## ##](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001980/python-regular-expression-matching)

Comment: i did, but people stopped responding on that one (figured it was too old)

Comment: Too old? It's less than an hour old... have some patience

Comment: sorry. good point, just eager to figure this out. would delete this point if i could =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with your inner match.  You use `.`, which matches *any* character that isn't a line end, and that means it matches `#` as well.  So when it gets `###hey##`, it matches `(.*?)` to `#hey`.

The easy solution is to exclude the `#` character from the matchable set:

```
prog = re.compile(r'##([^#]*)##')
```

Protip: Use raw strings (e.g. `r''`) for regular expressions so you don't have to go crazy with backslash escapes.

Trying to allow `#` inside the hashes will make things **much** more complicated.

(EDIT: Earlier version didn't handle leading/trailing `###` right.)

Comment: thanks, but it doesnt work for the string ####hey## =( lol

Comment: Moved my answer to your original question, look there.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s='lala ###hey## there'
>>> re.sub("(##[^#]+?)#+","FOUND",s)
'lala #FOUND there'

>>> s='lala ###hey## there blah ###### hey there again ##'
>>> re.sub("(##[^#]+?)#+","FOUND",s)
'lala #FOUND there blah ####FOUND'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

pattern = "(##([^#]*)##)"
prog = re.compile(pattern)

str = "lala ###hey## there"
result = prog.search(string)

line = "lala ###hey## there"

print re.sub(result.group(0), "FOUND", line)
```

The trick is to say (not #) instead of anything. This also assumes that

```
line = "lala #### there"
```

results in:

```
line = "lala FOUND there"
```

Comment: You don't need to put parens around the whole pattern; match group 0 is the whole matched input text.